# express-cassandra is converting Long value into negative

Tags: node.js, cassandra, express-cassandra

I am using `express-cassandra` npm package to connect to database, The below code is giving negative value while converting `Long` value into `Integer`.

```
var num = 13315766168394088000;
```

Result is:-

```
var valueFromInt = models.datatypes.Long.fromInt(num);
```

## => Long: -1152696320

```
var valueFromString = models.datatypes.Long.fromString(num.toString());
```

## => Long: -5130977905315463616

I don't understand why this is huge difference and why this is returning negative value.

Answer (score 2):

`13315766168394088000` is greater than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (2^53), so you should not represent it with a `Number` (64-bit IEEE-754 double) and you shouldn't use `Long.fromInt()`.

You could work with either the bits or the decimal string representation of the value:

```
const longValue = Long.fromString('13315766168394088000');
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the same thing while doing my research.